# Program to delete node/vertex from graph having out degree zero

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Program to delete a node from graph having out degree zero. Consider the following graph where M -no. of edge, N-no. of vertices, (u,v) edge.
M=6, N=6
1 2
1 3
1 6
2 3
3 4
3 5.
I want to delete 6, 5 & 4 from graph in any sequence.

Answer (score 5):

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5};
g1 = Graph[edges, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small];
```

You can use [`VertexDelete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDelete.html):

```
g2 = VertexDelete[g1, _?(VertexOutDegree[g, #] == 0 &)];
g3 = VertexDelete[g1, GeneralUtilities`GraphSinks[Graph[edges]]];
Row[Labeled[##, Top] & @@@ Transpose[{{g1, g2, g3}, Style[#, 16] & /@ {"g1", "g2", "g3"}}],
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]